# Position: "stickyfixed" - possible somehow?

Tags: css

This is my HTML structure for my site

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        ::before
        <header></header>
        <article></article>
        <article></article>
        <article></article>
        <article></article>
        <footer></footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

The header is normally `position:fixed` but on short viewports it's `static` so it scrolls out of view as normal.

`#container::before` has my site's photo background, `position:fixed`, so that it remains in place while the glass-effect `opacity:.9` `<article>`s scroll over it.  It's maybe a bit old-school, but it's a pleasing effect that I like and want to keep.

It's important to me though, that the background photo starts immediately below `<header>`, without any of it being cropped off underneath that element.  This is easy enough by modifying the `top` rule of that pseudo-element to match the (set) `height` value of the `<header>`.

...right up until the point where the `position:static` `<header>` scrolls off the page on a short viewport.

**What I want to happen**

I'd like for the background to scroll up along with the `<header>`, up until the point that the `<header>` is off the screen, and for it to then stick in place, as if it had `position:fixed;top:0`.

**What's my best option so far?**

`top:0` on the pseudoelement background if the `<header>` isn't `fixed`.  It works once the header is off the top of the screen, but it means an important part of the photo is cropped off when the header is on screen.

I could fix this with a JavaScript on-scroll event, but I know that'll be jerky and unperformant.  Is there some CSS trickery I can pull with my current HTML setup to overcome this?  Even if it's only supported in some browsers, it'd be better than nothing.

Comment: Not sure if i got your question right, but I think, what you are looking for, is position: sticky; top: 0; in your css. Also add position: -webkit-sticky;.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: It's not, I'm afraid - I wish it *were* that simple.